# Collaborate to create Anki decks

Tags: version-control, anki, collaboration

Not sure where to ask this question. It is **not** a software recommendation, more of a method recommendation.

I am gonna try to administer a collaboration among 10-20 persons to create an [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) deck to learn a new, foreign, language vocabulary and grammar. **The people involved think Excel is complicated.**

There are a few solutions for collaborating in Anki but generally, they involve JSON and Github etc. I repeat what I wrote in the previous paragraph: the members of my team think Excel is complicated (and most of them are middle-aged). I am not gonna introduce them to version control.

How can I make this collaboration effort simple enough? To give an example of what I think people will manage: if I could create a Google Sheet with columns named "frontside", "backside", "image", "sound" (pronunciation), "sample sentence" and maybe a few more I think most of them would understand and manage. (And Google Docs would take care of the version control.)

But then there is the problem that we are all novices learning a new language -> quite a few of the entries might be questionable and need editing and so on. In other words, we **ALSO** need a method to edit an existing note avoiding duplicates and similar issues.

Everything would be easy if Anki's webservice would allow "locking" of notes (and a smart method to modify the database) but it doesn't. Instead, a lot of operations makes sync-and-merge impossible, instead, you have to up-/download and replace everything.ä

Any ideas how I should organise this?